# zsh:killed command grep -q -Fx "$zcompdump_revision" "$ZSH_COMPDUMP" 2> /dev/null

Tags: command-line, iterm, zsh

This issue started occurring randomly yesterday and I cannot figure this out. Every time I launch `zsh`, I get the error mentioned below:

```
zsh: killed     command grep -q -Fx "$zcompdump_revision" "$ZSH_COMPDUMP" 2> /dev/null
zsh: killed
zsh: killed
[19]    65420 killed
[19]    65423 killed
```

[image]

I have tried uninstalling `zsh` and installing it again. I have also disabled all the plugins and themes in the `~/.zshrc` but that doesn't change anything.

After uninstalling and installing it again, I am unable to use most of the tools installed and set in the path in `~/.zshrc` now (e.g., `nvm`, `node`, `npm` etc).

Comment: Can you remove the redirection at the end and try again? This hopefully shows some error messages.

Comment: PS: Also, please copy/paste from Terminal as text. Screenshots aren‘t very useful for this.

Comment: @nohillside the error is pasted above the screenshot. That's all I am receiving in the terminal. `System.log` doesn't have anything related to this at all.

Apologies for asking, but how do I remove the redirect?

Comment: You need to edit .zshrc and remove the redirection (`2>/dev/null`) at the end of the line shown in the output.

Comment: @nohillside there's not such redirect (or even the command) present in the `.zshrc` file.

Comment: You may need to look in the files called/sourced there. You could also include the file in the question.

Comment: Please don't post text as an image; see [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320052/why-are-images-of-text-code-and-mathematical-expressions-discouraged).

Comment: @agarza I added the image for reference. The error, shown in the image, is also pasted as text/code snippet right above the image in the initial question edit itself!

Comment: @arximughal If you already have the information as text/code then there is **no need** for duplication of information.